# ubuntu - screen moved up - cuts all app title bars

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I have a ubuntu running in vmware - with host Mac Os x. I am not sure what keys I hit, but display has shifted up a bit for ubuntu vm. So any app I open, the title is out of reach.

[image: ubuntu vm - display is moved up a bit - terminal window top is cut off]

Can anyone suggest a fix.?

Thanks.

Comment: press f11 and see what happens. or resize the window.

Comment: Nothing happens with f11.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with this myself at this late date.

TL;DR: **Run "CompizConfig Settings Manager". Select "Window Management". Enable "Move Window".**

Environment: VMware® Workstation 17 Player in Windows 10 with virtual Ubuntu 16.04.

All new windows were being opened with the title bars just off-screen.

Hint from [Getting rid of self-resizing windows in Ubuntu Linux 12.04](https://earlruby.org/2012/04/getting-rid-of-self-resizing-windows-in-ubuntu-linux-12-04/).

In my case, everything worked fine on a macOS host, but transfer of Ubuntu to Windows resulted in this problem.